# CORS : OPTIONS 500() : Failed to load header

Tags: javascript, http

I have a problem with CORS. I can do a GET request but it's impossible to do a POST or PUT Request.

I use AWS API GateWay to do my API. My APi works with postman.

I have these errors: [error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fETm9.png)

My code :

```
postUsersHTTP(request:any): Promise<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Custom-Header"
    });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post(environment.baseURL + "/user", request, options).toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}

private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}

private handleErrorPromise (error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

I see a lot of answer on stackoverflow but not reallly usefull for my error Thanks !

Comment: add cors headers to your backend

Comment: it's a backend (server side) issue  please add cors on backend

Answer (score 0):

I've been there, I've done that!
that's call X-Scripting protection.
Install this extension to your Chrome, and you'll be good to go.

Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Yes i have see this but when i will put it in production, i will not have problem?

Comment: you can only make calls to your own domain.
make sure to put your AWS as a sub-domain of the production domain.